# C writes unexpected characters

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding

I've never really used C before but am trying to run this code: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/glove.c

Problem: when I read the utf8 character using this code and simply output that utf8 character, it outputs them differently.

Here is an example

```
    µl    Âµl 
    ｡    ï½¡ 
    ß    Ã<9f> 
    versión    versiÃ³n 
    ◘    â<97><98> 
    Léon    LÃ©on 
    Résumé    RÃ©sumÃ© 
    Cancún    CancÃºn 
    ������    ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿
```

The left side is what original word in `fid` and the right side is what this code outputs.

The `fprintf` is happening in line 234-237.

```
    if (fscanf(fid,format,word) == 0) return 1;

    if (strcmp(word, "<unk>") == 0) return 1;
    fprintf(fout, "%s",word);
```

The first line reads the word from `fid` in `format`. However, `format` is defined as `sprintf(format,"%%%ds",MAX_STRING_LENGTH);`. It doesn't have any information about encoding.

My question is: How does C know which encoding to read and output? On this file, I can't find how it defines encodings like utf8, ISO-8859, etc.

How should I make this code to write left side characters?

Any comment (short is fine too!) or some keywords that I should look up will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please don''t link to code, but put it right here. You should edit your question.

Comment: Hmm. There are C string functions that know about "wide characters"...it seems like this program wasn't written to use them.  For example, see [this page](https://linux.cn/doc/C/output/en/c/io/fwscanf.html) on some of the functions from `<wchar.h>`

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't know anything about whatever encoding you use for the input. The `fscanf` call will simply read space-delimited "characters", where each character is a single *byte*.

Comment: Thanks for the input! So what's the best way to make C printout left-side characters?